# selectbox with combo values in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I want a traditional multi-select box with multi-value combination appearing in each option. Is there something readily available that I can use?

My data structure looks like this and I need each of the items to appear as an option with all its sub-values(firstname, lastname, username)

```
"users": [{
        "sreddy@company.com": {
            "firstname": "sudhakar",
            "lastname": "reddy",
            "username": "sreddy"
        }
    }, {
        "tbaker@company.com": {
            "firstname": "tom",
            "lastname": "baker",
            "username": "tbaker"
        }

    }, {
        "slint@company.com": {
            "firstname": "sam",
            "lastname": "lint",
            "username": "slint"
        }
    }]
```

Here's the example of how I want it to appear. I saw this http://www.jplugins.net/magicsuggest/?demo, but the select box appears as a drop down but not as a traditional multi-select box which is what I need.
Please help! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: there are numerous plugins for this that can be found by web searches. Asking for suggested resources is not appropriate question on SO

Comment: What do you mean by "traditional multi-select box"? Any example out there?